# How to see what other people tweeted to someone

Tags: twitter

I just joined Twitter. For example let's take Dwayne Johnson. If I follow him and if I wanna see what other people have tweeted to Dwayne, what should I do or where should I go to see it?

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy. Please follow these steps to see what tweets people have been making to others,

1. Open Twitter
2. Go to the Twitter profile: twitter.com/{userHandle}
3. On the profile page, click on "Tweets & replies" link which is on the top of the tweets visible on the page.

As pointed out by @serenesat the same is available on the Android app under the "Tweets" section on a profile. It is also available on the mobile web version of Twitter.

Comment: In mobile app(Android), there is an option to see tweets of the people. Go to anyone's twitter profile and you will see three option: Tweets, Media, Likes. Under Tweets section all the tweets and replies will be there.